# Crew Dragon parachutes; "One of these things is not like the other..."

Tags: parachute

In blogs.nasa.gov's [Commercial Crew Program Testing Fosters Improvements in Parachute Safety](https://blogs.nasa.gov/commercialcrew/2019/09/17/commercial-crew-program-testing-fosters-improvements-in-parachute-safety/) there are photos of the four parachutes that bring Crew Dragon safely to back to Earth's surface, found first in this video in a [NASA Commercial Crew tweet](https://twitter.com/Commercial_Crew/status/1174406494839824385).

> As part of our program, @SpaceX has been testing the #CrewDragon parachute system, which consists of two drogue parachutes and four main ring-sail parachutes—the same type of parachutes that have been commonly used for human spaceflight in the past: https://go.nasa.gov/2LE2ALb

Why does one parachute have orange/white alternate stripes on the outside ring while the others have solid white?

[image: Crew Dragon parachute]

[image: Crew Dragon parachute]

Comment: There are 3 different parachute designs shown: broken stripes on the "dome" and white band (x1), unbroken stripes on the "dome" and white band (x2), and unbroken stripes on the "dome" and striped band (x1).

Comment: Oh, that's interesting!

Comment: Analysis of a whole or partial deployment failure might be easier with uniquely identifiable parachutes, though not sure these differences would actually help that much if they tangled together.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - all 4 chutes are different (one of your x2 has rotated apex) -- compare test 01 (not identical): https://youtu.be/B9eYCGOlr5Y?t=138  and uhoh, don't ignore the black fiducial rotation markers.

Comment: @aml awesome, then it probably comes down to being able to tell them all apart.